# SSIS File System Task Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have built a package using a `foreach loop` container and within that a `File System Task`. This is supposed to move and rename multiple files.

I'm using several variables of source and destination; and file name. It seems that variables are defined fine. All pointing to a V-drive.

When trying to run the package, it gives an error:

> "[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\destination_Filename.pdfFilename.pdf'."

I cannot figure out why is it actually trying to get into C-drive\program files, while I've defined clearly and completely different paths for both source and destination.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: I'm assuming you are applying the variables in an expression for the connection string defining your file name with each pass of the foreach loop.  Is the expression enabled under Properties?  If not, this could be the reason why it is still applying the C: default.  Is the default value for one of the variables defining the file "C:\...."?

Comment: If the project isn't given path(s) it will use the default location. I would try and debug variables...most likely the foreach is not seeing your chose paths.

Comment: @user3662215 : Well, I'm not sure, Where can I find these under properties?

Comment: @LeeEverest: What path do you mean exactly? It's given all the paths I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that your expression is not getting evaluated. Best way to debug is, in your for-each loop, put a `Script task`(C#), Pass on the variables and print it. Script to print:

```
public void Main()
{
 string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::test"].Value.ToString();
 MessageBox.Show(strMessage);

 Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

This won't immediately solve your issue, but will give you a checkpoint if problem persist after variable load or before.

Comment: I inserted the script task, but it didn't work. I've replaced the public part with yours, so now the script is supposed to look like this?

Comment: Yes...leave everything as it is. Just add `string` line and `MessageBox` line where it says `// TODO: Add your code here`

Answer (score 0):

script task:

```
    #region Help:  Introduction to the script task
/* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
 * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
 * 
 * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
 * Integration Services features within this script task. */
#endregion


#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace ST_e5bcf69902754e9cb85594ea888a4d08
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::test"].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(strMessage);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you replace the Variable names. I've used `test` as demonstration.